# Replace in result of other regex outcome

Tags: regex, bash, replace

I am trying to automate some things for my CentOS server. For this automation I need to add, replace or modify file lines. This works fine by doing a global replace or replacing unique lines.

`sed -i "s/user \\= apache/user \\= nginx/" file.conf`

This replaces `user = apache` with `user = nginx` which works fine.

But sometimes I need to replace lines like these within a result of an other regex. For example the file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` contains the same configuration lines for a serval times.
With a regex I can easily filter out the part I want to do my replaces in but I don't know how to do that.

This is a part of the file:

```
...
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://centos.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
exclude=postfix

[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
baseurl=http://centos.mirrors.ovh.net/ftp.centos.org/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
exclude=postfix

[extras]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Extras
...
```

With this regex:

`sed -n "/\[base\]/,/\[updates\]/p" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

I can get the lines from [base] until [updates]. Then I can modify for example `exclude` line. But how can I get these lines back into the main file?

This is what I have so far:

```
# $BASE contains the lines [base] until [updates]
BASE=`sed -n "/\[base\]/,/\[updates\]/p" /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

# Get te line that holds 'exclude' to the $EXCLUDE parameter
EXCLUDE=`echo "$BASE" | grep "exclude"`

# Modify EXCLUDE
EXCLUDE="$EXCLUDE, dovecot"

# Replace old exclude line in $BASE variable with new one
BASE=`sed "s/^exclude.*/$EXCLUDE/g" $BASE`

# Put $BASE back into /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
# ???
```

In this script I am trying to achieve this with multiple commands which is fine. It would also be nice if there is just one replace expression for this. But that of course is not a must.

Comment: remove `-n` switch and `p` command, just add your `s/search/replace/` after address range defined by your regex.. see http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3120/address-and-address-range#t=201609211113556376005 for examples

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i "/\[base\]/,/\[updates\]/s/^exclude.*/&, dovecot/"
```

`sed` commands consist of an optional address, the command, then any arguments to the command.  The address, if present, is either a single expression indicating the line number or single-line pattern identifying the line to which the command is to be applied, or a pair of comma-separated expressions indicating the starting and ending line numbers or patterns of the range to which the command is to be applied.

Your previous `sed` script (`"/\[base\]/,/\[updates\]/p"`) used the command `p` (print) with the address range of `/\[base\]/` to `/\[updates\]/`.

You can just apply your `s` (substitute) command to that same range, to substitute `exclude.*` (exclude followed by anything - but gobbling up the rest of the line) with `&, dovecot` (where `&` in the replacement string means everything that was matched).

If you need to do something more complicated within that address range, you can use the `{` sed command - which opens a block of commands that terminates with the `}` command.  This lets you do things like if/else blocks, so you could do:

```
sed -i -e "/\[base\]/,/\[updates\]/{" \
        -e "/\[base\]/h" \
        -e "s/^exclude=.*/&, dovecot/" \
        -e "/^exclude=/h" \
        -e "/\[updates\]/{" \
            -e "x" \
            -e "/^exclude=/b e" \
            -e "i \
exclude=dovecot" \
            -e ": e" \
            -e "x" \
        -e "}" \
    -e "}" /etc/yum.repos.d/...
```

This big hairy sed script does the following:

- everything in the script operates between the `[base]` and `[updates]` lines.
- The `[base]` line or any line that begins `exclude=` are placed into the "hold" buffer (via the `h` command)
- Any line that begins `exclude=` gets `, dovecot` appended to it
- When `[updates]` is seen:

  - the `hold` buffer is temporarily recovered (via the `x` command which swaps the current line with the `hold` buffer)
  - the buffer is checked to see if it begins with `exclude=`
  - if it does, skip the next line by branching (command `b`) to label `e`
  - if it doesn't (because we weren't skipped), insert the line `exclude=dovecot`
  - after label `e` (via the command `:`)...
  - swap the current line and `hold` buffer again (via `x` again)

In other words:  Any `exclude=` line gets `, dovecot` appended; if no `exclude=` line was seen, a new `exclude=dovecot` line is added at the end.

Note that it might be more useful to go from `/\[base\]/` to `/^$/`, if you can guarantee a blank line at the end of each block (which is normally the case), in which case the you would update the first `-e` expression as well as changing `-e "/\[updates\]/{"` to `-e '/^$/'{` (note also the change in quotes so that the `$` isn't parsed by the shell).